# the activity wouldn't start

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

i used tabhost and when i want to move to an new activity by a imagebutton  the emulator check those error

```
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.projet/com.projet.Inter_produit}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3057)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2837)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.projet.Accueil$1.onClick(Accueil.java:24)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-22 19:18:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(879):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 2):

Consider renaming your class (the file and the class name inside the file) from Inter_produit to InterProduit and add it to the Manifest.xml as an Activity.

Like this:

```
<activity android:name=".InterProduit"/>
```

If it is in your Applications package.